# Python Django как передать в ManyToMany отфильтрованные данные?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

У меня есть модель `Employee`, которая имеет `responsible: BooleanField` поле. Как мне передать в `models.ManyToMany` только тех `Employee`, у которых `responsible == True`?

Примерный набросок кода:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    responsible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)    # Тут необходимо применить фильтр
    ...
```

При попытке передать вместо `Employee` уже отфильтрованные данные (`Employee.objects.filter(responsible=True)`) получил ошибку "Надо передать модель".

Если нужна дополнительная информация - сообщите в комментариях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что вы хотите в поле employees отрендеренной формы модели Task видеть список только тех работников, responsible флаг которых равняется True.

В таком случае попробуйте создать отдельную форму и переопределить у неё метод init, в котором будете фильтровать список; затем, используйте новую форму при рендере:

```
from django import forms

class TasksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TasksForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employees'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(responsible=True)

@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TasksForm
```

[image: Результат работы кода]

Comment: Это именно то, что надо! А есть ли возможность сделать это на уровне модели, а не формы?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то на уровне модели это сделать нельзя. Возможно, кто-нибудь предоставит более подробную информацию позже.